# ViewBinding. NullPointerException. Missing required view with ID:

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewbinding

I have a new `Activity`, `CreatePadoqPromptActivity`, with a newly created layout called `activity_create_padoq_prompt.xml`.

Here is my button in the layout:

```
...
<com.padoq.android.core.ui.views.button.SolidGradientButton
        android:id="@+id/create"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="@string/feature_onboarding_create_group_prompt_title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        style="@style/OnboardingSplashTheme.ActionButton"/>
...
```

In my Activity I inflate the layout into a binding like so:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityCreatePadoqPromptBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

Pretty standard right? However I get the following exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with
> ID: myapp.debug:id/create
> at myapp.features.onboarding.databinding.ActivityCreatePadoqPromptBinding.bind(ActivityCreatePadoqPromptBinding.java:111)
> at myapp.features.onboarding.databinding.ActivityCreatePadoqPromptBinding.inflate(ActivityCreatePadoqPromptBinding.java:68)
> at myapp.features.onboarding.databinding.ActivityCreatePadoqPromptBinding.inflate(ActivityCreatePadoqPromptBinding.java:58)
> at myapp.features.onboarding.signup.createpadoqprompt.CreatePadoqPromptActivity.onCreate(CreatePadoqPromptActivity.kt:27)

Have checked other answers on here and none of the answers resolved the issues. To be clear, I use ViewBinding all the time in custom views, included layouts etc so I feel I know its quirks. This custom view has also been used in other layouts without issue.

For completeness, my custom view's constructor looks like so:

```
class SolidGradientButton @kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
```

Comment: What Version Of AS you are using ? And gradle plugin version too

Comment: I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2. Gradle plugin 7.0.2. Note, this happened on my previous Android Studio version. I only upgraded because I was running in to the issue

Comment: Are you using this in a Multi-module project? @StuStirling

Comment: I keep running into this issue (I also updated Android Studio due to it) and the only thing that usually works for me is to do a "Clean Project" from the "Build" menu. When that doesn't work I close Android Studio, delete the 'build' folder in the project and compile the lot from scratch. Doesn't really solve the problem - but helps when in a pinch.